# How to integrate odoo api with odoo database in flutter

Tags: api, flutter, connection, odoo

I am making an app that have odoo apis. Unlike REST they have functions urls. So i am just testing the code with these constants. But i am getting error when the server hit api. Can anyone tell me what i am doing wrong.

**Config file:**

```
class Config {
  static const SelfHostedUrl = true;
  static const HostUrl = 'https://duduslimmer-odoo-huge-stage-545860.dev.odoo.com/';
  static const PreConfigDatabase = false;
  static const PreConfigDatabaseName = 'duduslimmer-odoo-huge-stage-545860';
  static const SelfSignedCert = false;
  static const Timeout = 60000;
  static const LogNetworkRequest = true;
  static const LogNetworkRequestHeader = true;
  static const LogNetworkRequestBody = true;
  static const LogNetworkResponseHeader = true;
  static const LogNetworkResponseBody = true;
  static const LogNetworkError = true;
  const Config._();
}
```

**Dio Factory file:**

For connection to server. And i want to use this dio getter instance in calling odoo api.

```
import 'dart:io';

import 'package:cookie_jar/cookie_jar.dart';
import 'package:device_info/device_info.dart';
import 'package:dio/adapter.dart';
import 'package:dio/dio.dart';
import 'package:dio_cookie_manager/dio_cookie_manager.dart';
import 'package:dio_flutter_transformer/dio_flutter_transformer.dart';
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';
import 'package:odoo_json_rpc_flutter/config/config.dart';
import 'package:path_provider/path_provider.dart';

class DioFactory {
  static final _singleton = DioFactory._instance();

  static Dio get dio => _singleton._dio;

  static var _deviceName = 'Generic Device';
  static var _cookiesPath = './.cookies/';

  static Future<bool> computeDeviceInfo() async {
    if (Platform.isAndroid || Platform.isIOS) {
      DeviceInfoPlugin deviceInfo = DeviceInfoPlugin();
      if (Platform.isAndroid) {
        AndroidDeviceInfo androidInfo = await deviceInfo.androidInfo;
        _deviceName = '${androidInfo.brand} ${androidInfo.model}';
      } else {
        IosDeviceInfo iosInfo = await deviceInfo.iosInfo;
        _deviceName = iosInfo.utsname.machine;
      }
    } else if (Platform.isFuchsia) {
      _deviceName = 'Generic Fuchsia Device';
    } else if (Platform.isLinux) {
      _deviceName = 'Generic Linux Device';
    } else if (Platform.isMacOS) {
      _deviceName = 'Generic Macintosh Device';
    } else if (Platform.isWindows) {
      _deviceName = 'Generic Windows Device';
    }

    final directory = await getApplicationSupportDirectory();
    _cookiesPath = '${directory.path}/.cookies/';
    if (!kReleaseMode) {
      print('_cookiesPath is $_cookiesPath');
    }
    return true;
  }

  Dio _dio;

  DioFactory._instance() {
    _dio = Dio(
      BaseOptions(
        baseUrl: Config.HostUrl,
        headers: {
          HttpHeaders.userAgentHeader: _deviceName,
        },
        connectTimeout: Config.Timeout,
        receiveTimeout: Config.Timeout,
        sendTimeout: Config.Timeout,
      ),
    );
    _dio.interceptors.add(CookieManager(PersistCookieJar(dir: _cookiesPath)));
    _dio.transformer = FlutterTransformer();
    if (!kReleaseMode) {
      _dio.interceptors.add(LogInterceptor(
        request: Config.LogNetworkRequest,
        requestHeader: Config.LogNetworkRequestHeader,
        requestBody: Config.LogNetworkRequestBody,
        responseHeader: Config.LogNetworkResponseHeader,
        responseBody: Config.LogNetworkResponseBody,
        error: Config.LogNetworkError,
        logPrint: (Object object) {
          debugPrint(object, wrapWidth: 768);
        },
      ));
    }
    if (Config.SelfSignedCert) {
      final httpClientAdapter = _dio.httpClientAdapter as DefaultHttpClientAdapter;
      httpClientAdapter.onHttpClientCreate = _onHttpClientCreate;
    }
  }

  dynamic _onHttpClientCreate(HttpClient client) {
    client.badCertificateCallback = _badCertificateCallback;
  }

  bool _badCertificateCallback(X509Certificate cert, String host, int port) {
    return true;
  }
}
```

**CallAPi file:**

Calling this method from UI to get response and this use the instance of dio that was created in dio factory file.

```
  Future callingApi() async {
      Response response = await DioFactory.dio.get(
        "xmlrpc/2/common",
      ) .catchError((e, stackTrace) {
        print(stackTrace);
        if (e is DioError) {
          if (e != null) {
            print(e);
          }
        }
      });//catch error here
       print('Token: ${response.data}');
      return
        ;

  }
```

I simply want a response from server like the response came in the official documentation.  https://www.odoo.com/documentation/13.0/webservices/odoo.html#logging-in

**Response:**

```
{
    "server_version": "13.0",
    "server_version_info": [13, 0, 0, "final", 0],
    "server_serie": "13.0",
    "protocol_version": 1,
}
```

But i am getting null reposne when i used dio.get and when dio.post is used, i got this response.
can you please check where i am doing wrong, is i am passing correct urls and parameters and what type of request i have to give.[image]

Comment: be more specific, what do you need. Give an example.

Comment: I added more details. Sorry for inconvenience, before writing more details the questions gets pusblished.

Comment: You've mentioned that you got an error, could you provide the error message that you've encountered?